# can ecc and registered ram be used together

Tags: memory, ecc

do you know if it is possible to use both ECC and Registered DDR2 SDRAM in a server?

We have a mix of both, but when they are all installed, the server fails to boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Specifically, when using registered RAM, ALL modules in the system need to be registered. You can't mix and match.

Also: [see Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/kb/answer.aspx?qid=3669&aid=10273954&pid=3641024&sid=skim769x53352xab0f770280f350edaebc4e84b69c3b3f).